# Visual Studio Code/Powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

When running the PowerShell script in the attached photo using Visual Studio Code I get this-

Move-ADObject: The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

[image: Script]

If I run the exact script in PowerShell externally, it runs fine. I'm not sure why it will not run in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Change `Get-ADComputer $Comp` to `Get-ADComputer $using:Comp`

Comment: Whats the reason for using `Invoke-Command` in your code? its absolutely not doing anything useful since you're not connecting to any remote host

Comment: The script above runs fine on my coworker's Visual Studio Code.  -Mathias, no good-A Using variable cannot be retrieved. A Using variable can be used only with Invoke-Command, Start-Job, or InlineScript in the script workflow. When it is used with Invoke-Command, the Using variable is valid only if the script block is invoked on a remote 
computer."    -santiago, I'm not sure it's not my code as I'm just learning PowerShell, so any input is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with PowerShell 7, the script runs fine on PowerShell 5.1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).